# Simplifying a Bra-Ket Expression

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, operators, hamiltonian, linear-algebra

Consider the following relations

$$H_0|\psi_a\rangle = E_a|\psi_a\rangle$$
$$H_0|\psi_b\rangle = E_b|\psi_b\rangle$$

I am struggling then to understand why the following identity holds (its probably straight forward but I just can not see it.) Note that **r** represents the position operator.

$$   \langle \psi_b|  rH_0 - H_0r|\psi_a\rangle = (E_a - E_b)\langle \psi_b| r|\psi_a\rangle$$

Comment: Do you understand how $H_0$ operates on a *bra*?

Comment: I am unsure so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\langle\psi_b|H_0 = E_b\langle\psi_b|$. Hermitian operators can operate in either “direction”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that $H_0$ as an observable is hermitian $H_0 = H_0^\dagger$. That means you can use $$\langle\Psi_b|H_0 r|\Psi_a\rangle = (\langle\Psi_a|r^\dagger H_0^\dagger|\Psi_b\rangle)^\ast = (\langle\Psi_a|r^\dagger H_0|\Psi_b\rangle)^\ast$$

You might also just say that it is part of the definition of the bra-ket notation, that operators $A$ inside act as $A$ to the right and as $A^\dagger$ to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an alternate derivation that uses the expansion of unity:
$$
\mathbb{1}=\sum_c \vert \psi_c\rangle\langle \psi_c\vert
$$
rather than explicit hermiticity.

From
\begin{align}
\langle\psi_b\vert H_0 r\vert\psi_a\rangle=
\langle\psi_b\vert H_0\mathbb{1} r\vert\psi_a\rangle
=\sum_c\langle\psi_b\vert H_0\vert\psi_c\rangle\langle \psi_c\vert r\vert\psi_a\rangle\, . 
\end{align}
At this stage use $H_0\vert\psi_c\rangle = E_c\vert\psi_c\rangle$ to get
\begin{align}
\langle \psi_b\vert H_0 r\vert\psi_a\rangle &= \sum_c E_c\langle\psi_b\vert\psi_c\rangle\langle\psi_c\vert r\vert\psi_a\rangle\, ,\\
&=E_b\langle \psi_b\vert r\vert\psi_a\rangle,
\end{align}
where in the last step $\langle \psi_b\vert\psi_c\rangle=\delta_{bc}$ has been used to eliminate the sum.